# XSLT - XSL:FO PDF Table-Row to high - Unicode Block Elements in Tree

Tags: xslt, unicode, xsd, xsl-fo

I'm trying to build a Tree for a Parts-List, like that:

[image: The Tree]

But when I try to fit in a perpendicular Line (Courier New, HTML decimal: &#9474), it wont fit perfectly up to the next block element. I double checked all borders, margins and paddings.

I also thought that maybe the black element itself wouldn't fill the sign, space, but that isn't the case, as you can see on the picture. The element with the stripe to the right is the same size like the perpendicular line. And the element with the line to the right fits perfectly, the perpendicular line doesn't:

[image]

Here's the code of the nested together tables:

```
<fo:table-body>
[...]
<fo:table-row font-size="8pt" padding-top="0pt"
    margin-bottom="-3pt" margin-top="0pt" vertical-align="center"
    font-family="MyCourierNew">
    <fo:table-cell border-left="{$Standardrand}" font-size="11pt" font-family="MyCourierNew">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:if test="$ben2 != ''">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$naechste  &gt; $aktuelle">
                        │
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$naechste = $aktuelle and $aktuelle &gt; 1">
                        │
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

I seriously can't find the Problem.

Comment: Not sure there really will be solution to this, but perhaps you can try setting explicitly all the border-top and border-bottom on the `table-row` and on the `table-cell` to 0pt.

Comment: I doubt that your Courier New (or 'MyCourierNew') font has the box-drawing characters (unless you've added them to 'MyCourierNew').  See, e.g., http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/courier-new/courier-new/glyphs.html for the glyphs in Monotype's Courier New.  As such, your formatter is probably substituting glyphs from a different font anyway.  Also, it would help if you could add a snippet of the actual XSL-FO markup.  Lastly, setting `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to `0pt` and `line-height` to `1` might help.

Comment: @TonyGraham Setting the line-height to 1 fixed my problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what XSL-FO you are generating. But line-height.conditionality="discard" may help you. This property setting removes half-leading before and after the line. So it will suitable for this case.

Here is my formatting result that use &#9474;.

[image: Sample formatting result]

And here is my XSL-FO

```
<fo:table-and-caption>
    <fo:table border-after-width.conditionality="retain"
        border-before-width.conditionality="retain" border-bottom="2pt solid black"
        border-left="2pt solid black" border-right="2pt solid black"
        border-top="2pt solid black" font-size="9.5pt" space-after="2mm">
        <fo:table-column
            column-width="20mm" text-align="left"/>
        <fo:table-column
            column-width="40mm" text-align="left"/>
        <fo:table-column
            column-width="20mm" text-align="left"/>
        <fo:table-column
            column-width="20mm" text-align="left"/>
        <fo:table-body start-indent="3pt">
            <fo:table-row font-size="8pt" display-align="center" font-family="Arial">
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>35</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black" font-family="Courier New" font-size="11pt" line-height.conditionality="discard">
                    <fo:block>1</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>2</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>8247947</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row font-size="8pt" display-align="center" font-family="Arial">
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>35</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black" font-family="Courier New" font-size="11pt" line-height.conditionality="discard">
                    <fo:block>&#x2502;</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>2</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>8247947</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row font-size="8pt" display-align="center" font-family="Arial">
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>35</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black" font-family="Courier New" font-size="11pt" line-height.conditionality="discard">
                    <fo:block>&#x251C;2</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>2</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>8247947</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row font-size="8pt" display-align="center" font-family="Arial">
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>35</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black" font-family="Courier New" font-size="11pt" line-height.conditionality="discard">
                    <fo:block>&#x2502;</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>2</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>8247947</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row font-size="8pt" display-align="center" font-family="Arial">
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>35</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black" font-family="Courier New" font-size="11pt" line-height.conditionality="discard">
                    <fo:block>&#x2514;3</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>2</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-end-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid"  border-end-color="black">
                    <fo:block>8247947</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</fo:table-and-caption>
```

Comment: The `line-height.conditionality="discard"` worked for the perpendicular Line, but screw up the rest of my doc... But I Fixed it. :) Thank you for the effort!